# How to attach files to an email in Windows Phone 7.5 Mango

Tags: email, 7.x

In the default email client in Windows Phone 7.5 Mango, how can arbitrary files(.zip, .mp3, .txt, .pdf etc) be attached? AFAIK, the storage is sand-boxed, the file handler can implement hooks to the email client, as MS-Office does and Adobe Reader doesn't, but the email client can not access files in the Phone's storage.

Is there a way, or a work around? In my usage pattern, I tend to send a lot of .pdf files, and am unable to do that!

Answer (score 8):

You're only able to attach pictures to e-mails from the e-mail application. Consider using a more appropriate collaboration tool for documents, instead of sending them per email, such as OneDrive or Office 365.

For Office documents, open the documents on the phone, and press **share** in the the application-bar menu. This allows you to share a document using your email account(s), or OneDrive.

For OneDrive, you can share a link directly from the [OneDrive](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/apps/onedrive/9wzdncrfj1p3) application.

Comment: Yup, that's pretty much a huge limitation. In my use case, as I said, I tend to compose a lot of emails, and it becomes much of a hassle uploading and sending a link.

Comment: But you have to download the PDFs on the phone in the first place. Which begs the question, why are you doing this on the phone?

Comment: So, ok. How would I attach even a word file from within the email client? Surely you can compose one on the phone itself. And How do you attach two?

Comment: See my extended answer on how to share office documents by email or skydrive.

Comment: If speaking about app development, then please read this: [Pushing the limits of the Windows Phone SDK and sending files via EmailComposeTask](http://dennisdel.com/blog/pushing-the-limits-of-the-windows-phone-sdk-ndash-sending-files-via-emailcomposetask)

Comment: @ClausJørgensen, you probably did not notice the "from within the email client" part. Also the part where I ask " How do you attach two?". Anyway, I can now understand that the same is impossible.